# Wire up AngularJS controller to express controller

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm getting started with node/express/Angular by using the MEAN stack at [mean.io](http://mean.io).

I don't understand how the Angular controller calls the express controller to fetch data.

What I have is public/js/controllers/index.js:

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'Tabs', 
    function ($scope, Global, Tabs) {
        $scope.global = Global;
        Tabs.query(function(tabs) {
            $scope.tabs = tabs;
        });
}]);
```

But I'm confused what exactly 'Tabs' is. I know that somehow, magically, eventually this method is called - I think this is the Express controller?
app/controllers/tabs.js:

```
exports.all = function(req, res) {
    Tab.find().sort('artist').select("-content").populate('user').exec(function(err, tabs) {
    if (err) {
        res.render('error', {
            status: 500
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(tabs);
    }
});
};
```

But I don't understand how it gets called. What I want to do is call a different method in app/controllers/tabs.js instead - namely, this:

```
exports.newest = function(req, res) {
    Tab.find().sort('-created').limit(10).select("-content").exec(function(err, tabs) {
    ...
```

But I don't understand how to "wire up" the AngularJS controller with the express controller.

i.e. what do I have to do so that I can do something like this in my controller:

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'Tabs', 
    function ($scope, Global, Tabs) {
        $scope.global = Global;
        Tabs.newest(function(tabs) { // this won't work
            $scope.tabs = tabs;
        });
}]);
```

Comment: I would recommend that you do some getting started tutorials on angularjs, node, express, mongo (mongoose) first. You need at least some basics before you start with a boilerplate app which is ofthen more complicated to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In MEAN, The Articles service is an angular service that returns a $resource object you can usually find in the public/js/services folder.

$resource is a wrapper around $http AJAX service that comes with angularjs, it enables you to connect with RESTful endpoints if your REST service is built in a specific manner.

The connection to the the node.js controller happens using the routes.js object found in the config folder that binds routes to specific module methods.

further reading:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already had the routes.js wired up - I can hit http://localhost:3000/tabs/newest and it shows the data I want in JSON. I just can't figure out what I need to do to change in my controller to use this data.